# laravel, relaciones muchos a muchos error al intentar insertar una fila

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy trabajando con laravel 8, Mysql: 5.7.36-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server - (GPL)

El error que me da es cuando intento insertar una fila con la función `syncWithPivotValues()`, y me devuelve el siguiente error:

> 'Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ss_apk_db`.`guiones_fields`, CONSTRAINT `guiones_fields_field_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`field_id`) REFERENCES `fields` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `guiones_fields` (`field_id`, `guion_id`, `order`) values (4512096258, 2, 0)'

Aquí dejo mis migraciones y el método que se usa para insertar la fila, lo curioso es que cuando lo realizo desde el propio phpmyadmin si que me permite hacer el insert

¿Alguna idea de que esta sucediendo?

Guion.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Guion extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'guiones';
    protected $fillable = ['nombre','empresa_id'];
    protected $keyType = 'integer';

    public function fields(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Field','guiones_fields')->withPivot('order');
    }

    public function getOrderedFields(){
        return $this->fields()->orderBy('order')->orderBy('categoria_id')->get();
        // return $this->fields()->join('fields')
    }
}
```

Field.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Field extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['id','relationship','systemName','label',
                            'dataType','isRequired','isAvailableInContactManager',
                             'empresa_id','categoria_id'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'integer';

    public function guiones(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Guion','guiones_fields')->withPivot('order');
    }
    public function options(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Option');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\FieldsCategory','categoria_id','id');
    }    
}
```

```php
public function store(Request $request){
    // dd($request->except(['_token']));
    $request->validate([
        'nombre'=>'required'
    ]);
    $cuestionario = Guion::create([
        'nombre' => $request->nombre,
        'empresa_id' => Auth::user()->empresa->id
    ]);
    // dd($cuestionario);
    $cuestionario->fields()->syncWithPivotValues($request->fields,['order'=>0]);
    if ($cuestionario){
        $msg = "Guion creado satisfactoriamente";
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', $msg);
    }
    $msg = "Ocurrio un error creando el guión";
    return redirect()->back()->with('danger', $msg);
}
```

FieldsMigration

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFieldsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->bigInteger('id');
            $table->mediumText('relationship');
            $table->mediumText('systemName');
            $table->mediumText('label');
            $table->mediumText('dataType');
            $table->boolean('isAvailableInContactManager');
            $table->boolean('isRequired');
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('categoria_id')->default(1);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('empresa_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            

            $table->primary('id');
            $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('fields_categories');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('fields');
    }
}
```

GuionesMigration

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGuionesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('guiones', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('id')->autoIncrement();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('empresa_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            // $table->primary('id');
            $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('guiones');
    }
}
```

GuionesFieldsTableMigration

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGuionesFieldsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('guiones_fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('guion_id');
            $table->bigInteger('field_id');
            $table->integer('order');
            $table->timestamps();

            
            $table->foreign('field_id')->references('id')->on('fields');
            // $table->foreign('guion_id')->references('id')->on('guiones');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('guiones_fields');
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene `$request->fields`?

Comment: $request->fields contiene un array de identificadores

Comment: En el mensaje de error dice `insert into guiones_fields (field_id, guion_id, order) values (4512096258, 2, 0)' es 4512096258 el valor de un elemento del array? Y estas seguro de que existe en la tabla a la que referencia?

Comment: Si el valor es un elemento del array y el elemento existe antes de realizar el insert, he cambiado la función syncWithPivotValues por attach, y funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he cambiado la función syncWithPivotValues por attach, y funciona correctamente

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras solución al problema. Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido, sería ideal si pudieras añadir algo más de detalle como ¿cuál es la diferencia entre `syncWithPivotValues` y `attach`? ¿por qué usar uno sobre el otro solucionó el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.